# Classic ASP METADATA Tags Not Working - MDAC 2.8/WDAC 6.0 on a Windows 2008 Box Running IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

What I am trying to do is simple. I have some Classic ASP with include headers like the following referencing MDAC 2.5:

METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library"        UUID="{00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}" VERSION="2.5"

Now I am trying to call this same include file on a Windows 2008 box with IIS 7 using MDAC 2.8 with this:

METADATA TYPE="typelib" NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library"        UUID="{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}" VERSION="2.8"

My question is, why does this not work anymore? Has the tag reference changed? I ran MDAC checker and everything is installed correctly. What am I missing?
I am running on a Windows 2008 box with IIS 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just thinking aloud .. could it be an issue between integrated and classic pipeline ? try using classic pipeline if it is not the case..

Comment: @Gaby - I am using Classic pipelining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set your site to run on 32-bit mode.
[EDIT]
MDAC 2.5 is only 32 bits
MDAC 2.8 has 64 bit version

Comment: MDAC is 32 bit yet, so to be able to use it you must run the pool in 32 bits.

Comment: Right, but on a Windows 2003 machine - I am running 2008, it doesn't work that way since MDAC 2.8 is now WDAC. At any rate, the pool is already in 32-bit so that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: take a lok at Data Access Technologies Road Map, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx

Comment: Informative but still doesn't answer why the 2.8 Metatag would not work.

Comment: may be experiencing failure for security reasons, you have checked this possibility?

Comment: I figured it out and it was something non-related hah (feels dumb). Thanks for trying to help though Isalamon.

Comment: Is there any reason to NOT just upgrade to 2.8?  It runs in both 32 and 64 bit